# imagemin-pngquant cannot execute binary

Tags: npm, imagemin

I am trying to use imagemin with imagemin-pngquant to reduce images in an AWS Lambda function. Here is the code that I've made using the docs as a reference:

(image.data is the Buffer I'm creating from an axios `.get()` with `arrayBuffer` as the responseType)

```
// We want to minify the image before we upload it
                let converted_image = await imagemin.buffer(await image.data, {
                    plugins: [
                        imageminPngquant({
                            quality: [.55, .65],
                            speed: 8,
                            strip: true
                        })
                    ],
                })
```

However, when I try to use the pngquant plugin to compress pngs, it does not work. Here is the exact error that I'm getting:

`Error: Error: /var/task/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant: /var/task/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant: cannot execute binary file"}%`